# How to add effect or color filter in imagevew?

Tags: android-viewpager, imageview, effect

I have MainActivity. Where i use Viewpager and in it i use imagevew.
I use CustomAdapter for image sliding. 
With image View i show 568 images. And i want to add effect or color filter in imagevew. 
I want if i click on button so the effect/filter include on all the images.
When i use imagevew for 1 image so i can add effect easily but when i want add effect in all images which show in 1 imagevew with the help of viewpager it is not worked. 
Please provide suitable examples.

Comment: What means `it is not worked`? Any error, warning, exception?

Comment: No, no error. I tried a lot.

Comment: It's possible any problem with plugins or project structure. Any suggestion.

Comment: Pase cod of your Activity and Fragment

Comment: Mybe this will help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/ It's applicable to methods as well.

Comment: Please provide sampe code or any contact for detail example.

Comment: Apps don't crash without error. The reason your app crashes is in the logcat. You can view this in your IDE (Android Studio or whatever). Check the logcat and copy/paste the exception and stack trace into your question. Also add the relevant code snippet (the code that crashes) to the question.

Comment: When i build the app its build successfully. And when i try on mobile it is crashes when i click on button in which i call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely positively cannot create an instance of an `Activity` using the `new` keyword. Only the Android framework can instantiate instances of Android components (`Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Provider`).

If you want to call a method in another class, then you need to declare the method as `static`. Then you may call the method from anywhere you want.